# What is this type of initialization called and why is it used?

Tags: java

Animal is a user defined class here.

```
Animal D = new Animal("Leo") {

        @Override public void makeNoise() {

              System.out.println("Roar!");

       }

};   D.makeNoise();
```

Answer (score 4):

Its called an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and used to define the class and any overridden methods at the same time.

Comment: There is an extension of this for Single-Method-Interfaces now that is even more concise (probably does not apply here, but good to know if you use Java8).

Comment: " define the class": Where "class" is a *subclass* of the class (or interface) named by `new`. So it does not instantiate `Animal` here, but an anonymous subclass instance.

Answer (score 0):

That is an anonymous class. For details about anonymous classes and why they are useful, see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) on anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is used to override the initial

```
Animal.makeNoise()
```

method with a custom one for just this instance.